# aws compute optimizer - change instance arquitecture type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The aws compute optimizer told us to change the intancia type. Below are the differences:

[image]

The instance running today is t3.small with debian 12.

My question is about the type of architecture. Can I switch from x86_64 to arm64?

Comment: did you try to switch?

Comment: I haven't changed anything yet. I'm researching to see if there's any problem. I believe it shouldn't be, as it was AWS itself that indicated the new instance type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will not work. You cannot just change the architecture of the instance. Even though that is what AWS compute optimizer suggested, they didn't mean that you can change the instance type to some graviton instance. Migration that they proposed is possible, but it will be a longer process:

- Create a new Graviton instance
- migrate data to the new instance
- test that your application works

You can also see more detailed steps explained in [Migrate an EC2 Linux instance to a Graviton instance | AWS re:Post](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-migrate-to-graviton).